# View Key of Monero Core Development Team donation account

Tags: viewkey, core-development-team

Does the core development team publish the view key of its [donation account](https://getmonero.org/getting-started/donate/) so that current and prospective donors can see how much XMR has been donated so far?

Although donated funds are spent solely at the discretion of the core team, has there been any voluntary disclosure of how donated funds are being used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The donation address and its view key are also found in the README.md file in the bitmonero repository. They can be verified by a GPG signature there: https://github.com/monero-project/bitmonero/blob/master/README.md, quoting:

> The Monero donation address is: 44AFFq5kSiGBoZ4NMDwYtN18obc8AemS33DBLWs3H7otXft3XjrpDtQGv7SqSsaBYBb98uNbr2VBBEt7f2wfn3RVGQBEP3A (viewkey: f359631075708155cc3d92a32b75a7d02a5dcf27756707b47a2b31b21c389501)

Note that, as it is, using the view key can tell you how much was received, but also change if monero was sent from that address. Change can be substantial, especially if it accumulates with small spends.

In order to see the full balance after any spends, you'd need to import a list of signed key images (a very recent addition to the monero simplewallet). Since it's a very new addition, I doubt anyone used that ability yet.

I think the clearest I've seen about donations and expenses can be found under the "Finances" heading at https://getmonero.org/2016/02/10/monero-missive-2015-year-in-review.html

Answer (score 6):

The viewkey for that address is:

f359631075708155cc3d92a32b75a7d02a5dcf27756707b47a2b31b21c389501

(Taken from https://github.com/fluffypony/bitmonero)

Remember, though, that a viewkey only allows you to see any incoming transactions.  It does not allow you to see the spent outputs of the address, so it doesn't function the same way as looking up a bitcoin address on blockchain.info.

Comment: The address is the same one as in the link far as I can tell.

Comment: Ah you're right.  I had originally pulled an address and viewkey from https://github.com/monero-project/monero-core and then found one from the more recent bitmonero repository.  Nice catch :)